# Tkinter window and script freeze when filedialog is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ffmpeg

Im developing a audio player for python. Unfortunately, it appears as if after a modification, the file dialog portion of the script ceased working. The code below is a minimum reproducible example of the offending bit.

```
# -----------------------Setup-----------------------
# Imports
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from tkinter import filedialog

import simpleaudio
import subprocess

# GUI
root = Tk() 
root.title("CupPlayer") 
menubar = Menu(root)
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
root.config(menu = menubar)
# ----------------------Functions---------------------
def file_selector(): 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
    root.update()
    if filename.endswith('.mp3'):
            subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', filename,
                                'audio.wav'])
btn = Button(root, text = 'search file !', bd = '5', 
                          command = file_selector) 

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @RandomInternetPerson first of all dont use `subprocess.call` inside a ui loop at all its make freeze and crashing the ui it will wait until subprocess process is open so change it to `subprocess.Popen` and check if it fixed